# cannot edit global template preferences

Tags: templates, database, permissions

I have a weird scenario where I am trying to edit my global template preferences. I change a simple dropdown or field, hit submit, and get a successful indicator (the green icon at the top of the screen) but the field has not changed. I output all template debugging and there doesn't seem to be any errors, but all changes are reverted to what they were before. I verified file permissions on database.php and config.php were 666. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest checking your config.php file and see if any of those global template preferences are explicitly set in your configs. If you are using FocusLab master config, I would check config.master.php and your individual environment configs.

Comment: I agree. If any config variables are hard-coded in config.php or FocusLab Master Config, those will override any database-side changes you make.

Comment: Yep - that was it - someone hardcoded a custom directory for the templates. Oddly though - it was preventing me from changing "save template revisions". Might have removed some other logic in that file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reuploading your Themes directory. It's possible something is missing or corrupted.

Also, look for JS errors in the console that might be causing an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. No JS errors, but I did end up reverting to an old version of config.php